# Limit inheritance/derivation of an abstract class (only pure virtual functions) to a certain class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class, derived-class

Given is an abstract class `AbstractParentPrinter` (i.e. with a pure virtual function):

```
class AbstractParentPrinter {
public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

`AbstractPrinter` is an (abstract) sub class of `AbstractParentPrinter`:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<AbstractPrinterStore, T>::value>>
class AbstractPrinter : public AbstractParentPrinter {
protected:
  T& getPrinterStore() {
        return printerStore;
    }
private:
  static T printerStore;
};
template<typename T>
T AbstractPrinter <T>::printerStore;
```

`PrinterA` is a sub class of `AbstractPrinter<PrinterStoreA>`. `PrinterStoreA` is a sub class of `AbstractPrinterStore` (not showed).

```
class PrinterA : public AbstractPrinter<PrinterStoreA> {
public:
  void print() {
   // Do something with PrinterStoreA and print
   // An AbstractPrinterStore here instead would be not sufficient
   std::cout << "Printer A has printed!" << std::endl; 
  }
};
```

As `AbstractPrinter<T>` (merged with `AbstractParentPrinter`) can't be stored in a `std::vector`, I've created a parent non-templated class `AbstractPrinter` for this purpose. How can I prevent a derivation from `AbstractParentPrinter` except in `AbstractPrinter`?

Comment: Do you really have to? There's probably some terribly advanced template trickery that lets you do that, but is it really worth adding tons of otherwise useless, hard to decypher boiler plate for this?

Comment: What is the point of having this abstract class if it can only be derived by one class? Why not merge both?

Comment: @antred I've added additional code / context to give a motivation for my question.

Comment: @RedX If I would merge AbstractParentPrinter and AbstractPrinter I would get a templated class which can't be stored in a std::vector (see last paragraph of my question).

Comment: maybe just write a comment not to inherit from `AbstractParentPrinter` and why, so that you in the future and everyone else maintaining this code  will know what's happening

Comment: @slawekwin I would prefer additionally a compile-time check, but if there is really no solution, I would only go this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the constructor of your most basic class private and then make the class you want to derive from it a friend of it.

```
class AbstractParentPrinter
{
    private: AbstractParentPrinter()
    {}

    template<typename t> friend class AbstractPrinter;
};
```

Another approach is to restrict any use of the class (not just inheritance), for example with an anonymous namespace or by making it a nested class.

====Simple general case answer to the question as in the title ends here====

In your case might consider changing the structure so to use the non-virtual interface pattern. You'd create a non-template class that you can keep in your vector, which would own a pointer to one of the templated versions. It's a use of the pImpl pattern.

```
class AbstractParentPrinter;

class Printer
{

    AbstractParentPrinter* pImpl;


    public:

    void print();

    //add some constructor code/declaration to initialise pImpl to the correct template      

};
```

you can either nest AbstractParentPrinter in Printer or forward declare it as above. If you nest it you could use std::unique_ptr, otherwise you'll delete it in printer's destructor.

in a cpp

```
class AbstractParentPrinter
{
    public: virtual void print() = 0;
};

// insert the template definitions here if you like

void Printer::print()
{
    pImpl->print();
}
```

The templates can even go in the same cpp (yes templates in a cpp - the whole point of usually having to put them in header files is to make them accessible to other code, but I'm assuming the motivation for your question is to hide these implementation details)

So you've still got your original base class and the templates that implement print, but now you've got an extra non-abstract, non-template Printer class, but there are other benefits from having that class. Your consuming code doesn't need to know about the abstract class and the templates - it can just have a vector of Printers, it doesn't need to deal in pointer to Printer, so that can make managing the lifetime of the printer objects easier.
The extra layer that the Printer class creates can also isolate calling code from changes in the implementations of the various print classes.

Comment: Can you give an example for the application of the non-virtual interface pattern in my case?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I would have for each AbstractPrinter<T>, i.e. AbstractPrinter<PrinterStoreA>, AbstractPrinter<PrinterStoreB>, ... an additional class. Right?